# how to find specific value is in key or not

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find data in mongodb. i am having data like this

```
{"name":"xxxx","product":"laptop,phone,mobile"}
{"name":"yyyy","product":"phone,iphone,pendrive"}
```

i am trying to find "phone" is in product key so i have tried this command in terminal

```
db.collection.find({"product": /phone/});
```

it is working fine but it is not working in my application.so i have tried dynamically like that in my application.

```
var key=phone;
var name="/"+key+"/"; 
collection.find({"product":name}).toArray(function(err,result)
{
   console.log(result.length);
});
```

but i am always getting 0 length only so how to use that dynamically?

Answer (score 4):

You're searching for 2 different things each time. In the terminal you're searching for occurrences of the word phone with a regular expression. In your application you are searching for occurrences of the string literal '/phone/'. You need to do a regex search in your mongodb query in your app as well:

```
var key = 'phone';
collection.find({"product":{ $regex: key }).toArray(function(err,result) ...
```

Comment: i am getting out put when will i give related character  like p and related string like phone. but i want data only when will i give exact string like phone. how to find ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var key = 'phone';
var reg = RegExp('.*'+key+'.*','gi');
collection.find({"product":{ $regex: reg }).toArray(function(err,result){

}
```

if your key appears in between in the string also this will work

Comment: i am getting same output.i must get data from db if i give phone otherwise my result should be zero.if i give p and ph and pho my retrive result length should be zero.so let me know correct solution to resolve it.

Comment: then just use var reg = RegExp(key,'gi');